# How to create a list of the images in a folder with the nodes refering to them?

Tags: 7, media

I would like to cleanup the folder sites/default/files by removing all images that belonged to a node that already has been deleted. Or would deleting a node, also delete the images it is showing in the body?

So, how can I know which images are no longer in use? Is there a tool to show which nodes are linking to the images? or to show images that are not linked to from anywhere in the site?

Comment: Thanks, no surprise this has been asked before, but I could not find it myself.

Comment: Quick tip about "finding" a question on this site: start typing the title to ask a new question, in which you mostly use possible / relevant keywords. And then look at the various question titles that show up while typing. In my experience way easier to "search" on this site ...